# HTML image resize downscale bad quality

Tags: html, rescale, image-quality

I have a development made.

I'm using 430px X 455px images

When I down-scaled image to 184px width:
- Google Chrome: looks perfect
- Firefox (37.0.1) looks very unfocused
- Internet Explorer (11.0.9): "sawtooth" look (very pixelated)

Why is this? Not rescaled images I can use?

What solution could there be?

Development: http://s566904160.mialojamiento.es/desarrollo/

[image: Bad quality images]

Answer (score 0):

Use object-fit property of CSS.. Read this tutorial 
http://www.devtantra.com/273/object-fit-css3/

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound by latency concerns, consider serving ~25% more pixels than you're specifying in CSS, and let the browser do the downsizing.  That will also handle cases such as browser zoom.

Answer (score -1):

You get the best image quality when using images in the desired resolution.
that can be achieved either by creating them in a tool like Gimp or Photoshop, or using libraries like ImageMagic.